# why did ThymeleafViewResolver not work?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I want to have two template resolver BEANs in one project.

first template resolver is using already. it works well.

```
    @Bean
    public ITemplateResolver feTemplateResolver(SpringResourceResourceResolver thymeleafResourceResolver) {
        String prefix = "classpath:fe20/is/templates/";
        boolean cacheable = true;

        if (environment.acceptsProfiles(LOCAL)) {
            String localResourcePath = environment.getRequiredProperty("FEB_HOME");

            prefix = "file:///" + localResourcePath + "/is/templates/";
            cacheable = false;
        }

        TemplateResolver resolver = new TemplateResolver();
        resolver.setResourceResolver(thymeleafResourceResolver);
        resolver.setPrefix(prefix);
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode(StandardTemplateModeHandlers.LEGACYHTML5.getTemplateModeName());
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        resolver.setCacheable(cacheable);
        resolver.setOrder(0);

        return resolver;
    }
```

and i added anthoer resolver for thymeleaf like,

```
    @Bean
    public ServletContextTemplateResolver servletContextTemplateResolver() {
        ServletContextTemplateResolver servletContextTemplateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        servletContextTemplateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:resources/templates/");
        servletContextTemplateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        servletContextTemplateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        servletContextTemplateResolver.setOrder(1);

        return servletContextTemplateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine springTemplateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine springTemplateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        springTemplateEngine.setTemplateResolver(servletContextTemplateResolver());

        return springTemplateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        thymeleafViewResolver.setTemplateEngine(springTemplateEngine());

        return thymeleafViewResolver;
    }
```

and then i run this app, request correct url, then i get an error

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving
>   template "statistics/index", template might not exist or might not be
>   accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

**THE QUESTION IS,**
through so many troubles,
i solved this problem by removing SpringTemplateEngin/ThymeleafViewResolver BEANs. so the remained BEAN is only ServletContextTemplateResolver.

**why did ThymeleafViewResolver not work?**

**and why did it works when i use only ServletContextTemplateResolver BEAN?**

Comment: I had a similar issue where it was causing errors from the css/js files. I used your solution and the errors stopped, but I can't figure out how to render css/js. I abandoned the WEB-INF and using src/main/resources -- templates and static directories. I can't get it to work. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Complicated way to configure, XML is so easy and less problematic than java conf.